# How to avoid redirection in google-sheet app script

Tags: google-apps-script

[image]

I have created a Google Sheet App Script and published as web app.
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyqUxINw93wmWPouXb7nOjt2886FBj6HBKg9sMF1B4rMN0I1xFG/exec

While i tried to POST data to this url, it's redirect to another URL.
How i can avoid this redirection.?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use **ContentService**. if you are using **ContentService** for returning JSON data. it will redirect to another URL. That's why your are getting 302 response.

```
return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(result))
.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
```

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content#redirects

Comment: did you write a doPost(e) method?

Comment: @Aerials Yes.. I'm using doPost(e) function

Comment: Is there another alternative/work around ? if someone doesn't need to use redirection?

Comment: @DimitrisTsarouhas you can use  HTMLService

Comment: @newbie, I tried that and got a bunch of html and javascript and not the content I entered into HtmlService.createHtmlOutput()

Comment: ContentService responses work with axios, but not fetch.